# EPPlus is not allowing excel download in IE, but works fine in Firefox.

Tags: .net, internet-explorer

I have a 'Download' button that creates an excel file and then opens it. It works perfectly fine in Firefox, but clicking on the button does absolutely nothing in IE. Does anyone have any idea why, or how to fix it? Here is the code:

```
<div align="center" id="excelDiv" runat="server">
    <a id="excelDownloadLink" runat="server">
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmitDownload" value="Download" />
    </a>
    <br /><br />
    <span id="validationResults" style="color:Red"></span><br />
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        excelDownloadLink.ServerClick += new System.EventHandler(ExcelDownload);

        DataCounts.DataSource = db.GetRequestCountByState();
        DataCounts.DataBind();
    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
           server control at run time. */
    }

    public void ExcelDownload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime startDateVal = DateTime.Parse(startDate.Value.ToString());
        DateTime endDateVal = DateTime.Parse(endDate.Value.ToString());

        if (searchType.Value == "Requests by Status")
        {

            DataSet statusExtract = db.GetStatusExport(startDateVal, endDateVal);
            DataTable statusExtractTable = statusExtract.Tables[0];

            DumpExcel(statusExtractTable, "Requests by Status");
        }
        else if (searchType.Value == "Database Extract")
        {
            DataSet dataExtract = db.GetDataExport(startDateVal, endDateVal);
            DataTable dataExtractTable = dataExtract.Tables[0];

            DumpExcel(dataExtractTable, "Database Extract");
        }
    }

    private void DumpExcel(DataTable tbl, string type)
    {
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            //Create the worksheet
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Database Extract");

            //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
            ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromDataTable(tbl, false);
            Response.Clear();

            switch (type)
            { 
                case "Database Extract":
                    //Header Titles
                    ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "RequestNumber";
                    ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "State";
                    ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "Status";
                    ws.Cells["D1"].Value = "Queue";
                    ws.Cells["E1"].Value = "OEM";
                    ws.Cells["F1"].Value = "Raytheon Material Number";
                    ws.Cells["G1"].Value = "Mfg Part Number";
                    ws.Cells["H1"].Value = "Material Charge Number";
                    ws.Cells["I1"].Value = "Program";
                    ws.Cells["J1"].Value = "Purchase Order";
                    ws.Cells["K1"].Value = "Purchase Requisition";
                    ws.Cells["L1"].Value = "Business Unit";
                    ws.Cells["M1"].Value = "Site";
                    ws.Cells["N1"].Value = "Buyer";
                    ws.Cells["O1"].Value = "Requisitioner";
                    ws.Cells["P1"].Value = "Component Engineer";
                    ws.Cells["Q1"].Value = "Responsible Engineer";
                    ws.Cells["R1"].Value = "Quality Engineer";
                    ws.Cells["S1"].Value = "Item Type";
                    ws.Cells["T1"].Value = "Material Location";
                    ws.Cells["U1"].Value = "Justification";
                    ws.Cells["V1"].Value = "Internal Testing Required";
                    ws.Cells["W1"].Value = "External Testing Required";
                    ws.Cells["X1"].Value = "Create Date";
                    ws.Cells["Y1"].Value = "Create Comments";
                    ws.Cells["Z1"].Value = "Closed Date";
                    ws.Column(26).Style.Numberformat.Format = @"m/d/yy h:mm:ss AM/PM";
                    ws.Cells["AA1"].Value = "Cancelled Date";
                    ws.Column(27).Style.Numberformat.Format = @"m/d/yy h:mm:ss AM/PM";
                    ws.Cells["AB1"].Value = "qty";
                    ws.Cells["AC1"].Value = "Minimum Buy Qty";
                    ws.Cells["AD1"].Value = "Broker Name";
                    ws.Cells["AE1"].Value = "Second Tier Supplier";
                    ws.Cells["AF1"].Value = "Requisitioner Date";
                    ws.Column(32).Style.Numberformat.Format = @"m/d/yy h:mm:ss AM/PM";
                    ws.Cells["AG1"].Value = "Requisitioner Comments";
                    ws.Cells["AH1"].Value = "CE Date";
                    ws.Column(34).Style.Numberformat.Format = @"m/d/yy h:mm:ss AM/PM";
                    ws.Cells["AI1"].Value = "CE Comments";
                    ws.Cells["AJ1"].Value = "REA Date";
                    ws.Column(36).Style.Numberformat.Format = @"m/d/yy h:mm:ss AM/PM";
                    ws.Cells["AK1"].Value = "REA Comments";
                    ws.Cells["AL1"].Value = "PQE Date";
                    ws.Column(38).Style.Numberformat.Format = @"m/d/yy h:mm:ss AM/PM";
                    ws.Cells["AM1"].Value = "PQE Comments";
                    ws.Cells["AN1"].Value = "PQE Customer Approval";
                    ws.Cells["AO1"].Value = "PQE NFD Purchase Request Approval";
                    ws.Cells["AP1"].Value = "PQE Additional Internal Testing";
                    ws.Cells["AQ1"].Value = "PQE Additional External Testing";
                    ws.Cells["AR1"].Value = "REA NFD Purchase Request";
                    ws.Cells["AS1"].Value = "REA Additional Internal Testing";
                    ws.Cells["AT1"].Value = "REA Additional External Testing";
                    ws.Cells["AU1"].Value = "MA Date";
                    ws.Column(47).Style.Numberformat.Format = @"m/d/yy h:mm:ss AM/PM";
                    ws.Cells["AV1"].Value = "MA Approval";
                    ws.Cells["AW1"].Value = "MA Comments";

                    ws.Column(1).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(2).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(3).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(4).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(5).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(6).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(7).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(8).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(9).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(10).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(11).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(12).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(13).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(14).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(15).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(16).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(17).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(18).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(19).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(20).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(21).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(22).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(23).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(24).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(25).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(26).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(27).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(28).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(29).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(30).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(31).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(32).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(33).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(34).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(35).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(36).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(37).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(38).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(39).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(40).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(41).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(42).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(43).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(44).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(45).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(46).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(47).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(48).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(49).AutoFit();
                    break;

                case "Requests by Status":
                    ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "RequestNumber";
                    ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "Status";
                    ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "Queue";
                    ws.Cells["D1"].Value = "OEM";
                    ws.Cells["E1"].Value = "Raytheon Material Number";
                    ws.Cells["F1"].Value = "Mfg Part Number";
                    ws.Cells["G1"].Value = "Material Charge Number";
                    ws.Cells["H1"].Value = "Program";

                    ws.Column(1).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(2).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(3).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(4).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(5).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(6).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(7).AutoFit();
                    ws.Column(8).AutoFit();


                    break;
            }      

            //Format the header for all columns
            using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:AW1"])
            {
                rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                //Set Pattern for the background to Solid
                rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                //Set color to dark blue
                rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(79, 129, 189));
                rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            }

            using (ExcelRange cols = ws.Cells["C1:C2000"])
            {

            }



            //Write it back to the client
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=NFDDatabaseExtract.xlsx");
            Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());

            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you look into loops a bit in order to replace code like this: ws.Column(1).AutoFit(); ws.Column(2).AutoFit(); ...

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that was definitely a place to put a loop. I was trying to figure out how to get the Epplus to work properly, and guess I just overlooked basic programming practices. haha I figured out the issue, too. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Created a server control (asp:Button) instead, and just used the OnClick event for the server control, and pointed it to ExcelDownload. I know that I've had issues before with IE naming controls differently than IE, maybe that was the problem. Not sure, but anyways, that fixed it.